# Azure AD Graph API demo example won't work: The identity of the calling application could not be established

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to get this demo to work:

[active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console)

But having no success. The steps are very detailed, and I followed them exactly. The userpart of the demo works, that's fine. But the app part won't work.
I'm getting the error:

> The identity of the calling application could not be established.
>   {"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_IdentityNotFound"}}

Googled for this, but givens me very few hits. Some with the same problem, but no solutions.

I'm pretty sure my clientId and key are correct, because when I change them I get another error clearly stating the problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this turns out to be some kind of bug in the portal.

I found a suggestion somewhere online that the new azure portal doesn't work well in this situation and tried to login to the old portal.

In the new portal I've created two app registrations, one for the user and one for the app.

In the old portal only one shows up, only the user one. So I've created a new app registration in de OLD portal, and everything started to work.

Comment: Great to see that you have this working. However is there a reason that you are using AAD Graph API vs Microsoft Graph API?  For the most part Microsoft Graph should cover all Directory functionality, and we have samples using Microsoft Graph for this.  Please see the NOTE at the beginning of the sample readme.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.. totally missed that comment trying to get it to work I guess. Will the aad graph be deprecated? I will switch to the ms graph.

Comment: So.. I tried to use the MS Graph API. But I'm stuck, does that also support AppMode (using clientid & cleintsecret) I cannot find any demo of that. tnx

Answer (score 0):

I am testing both for the demo app and custom app register by myself. And both worked well. Here are the steps for the custom app:

1. register the app on the my test tenant
2. change the ClientId, ClientSecret, TenantName, TenantId based on the application I registered
3. run the application
4. choose **a** to run app-only mode
5. search the users by input the character and below is the figure for the result

[image]

To narrow this issue, would you mind sharing the detail steps you were testing?

Comment: please see my own answer. Did you use the old or the new azure portal?

Comment: I was testing using the old portal.